How to export a Blender file into Parasolid, .ACIS, or .STEP?
How can I export a Blender file into Parasolid, .ACIS, or .STEP?

Parasolid and ACIS are a proprietary formats. They are also predominantly solid geometry formats. Blender doesn't work with solids. While it might be possible to export tesselated meshes to some of those, I don't think it will what you expect.
